# Conditionally swap keys on a keyboard (Debian, X11, KDE Plasma)

Tags: x11, kde, keyboard-layout

I have this keyboard layout on my Dell Latitude

[image: Keyboard layout]

It really grinds my gear that the `Home` and `End` Keys are mapped to the composite `Fn` key. So I managed to swap `PageUp` with `Home` and `PageDown` with `End` by adding this to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de` (actually, it's a german variant)

```
xkb_symbols "basic" {
  ...
  key <HOME> {    [  Prior        ]   };
  key <PGUP> {    [  Home         ]   };
  key  <END> {    [  Next         ]   };
  key <PGDN> {    [  End          ]   };
  ...
}
```

It's working as expected. However, quite frequently I am switching between my laptop as is and my work desk using a docking station and a full blown keyboard where this hack is annoying.

Manipulations of this xkb symbols files require a reboot (or at least a restart of the desktop environment). Is there any possibility to switch the behavior at runtime? Maybe even automated, like an udev hook seeing the USB-C dock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch between layouts with `setxkbmap`.  For example, I use Dvorak
layout, I applied your changes to my local
`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de` and switched to the German layout:

```
setxkbmap de
```

I checked if PGUP works as Home, it does.  I then switched back to
dvorak:

```
setxkbmap dvorak
```

If you want to switch between an original layout and your custom layout I think the
best way is to remove the 4 lines you showed in your question from an original `de` layout file
and create a new custom layout file, say
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de-modified with the modifications added.  There
will be no reboot and no X restart required to switch between the 2
layouts:

```
setxkbmap de # PGUP wouldn't work as home
setxkbmap de-modified # PGUP would work as home
```

Comment: cool, that's what i needed